# Trying to add an item to an array

Tags: java

```
/**
 * Creates and returns an array of media items that match the call number.
 * The length of the returned array is equal to the number of media items
 * that match the call number, and each element in the array is one of the
 * matching media items.
 * 
 * @param callNumber the call number of the media items
 * @return an array of matching media items.
 */
public MediaItem [] findItems(String callNumber)
{
    MediaItem[] tmp = new MediaItem[MAX_ITEMS];
    for (int i = 0; i <= inventory.size(); i++)
    {
        int j = inventory.indexOf(callNumber);
        
        tmp.add(inventory.get(j));
        return tmp;
    }
    
}
```

The description of the method is included,I am trying to add to the array created tmp, but using .add() doesn't work because for this project the object added is a MediaItem, not an int or a String, so I don't know what to do.

Comment: I recommend reading a basic tutorial on arrays, e.g. [this one by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Comment: `tmp[i] = inventory.get(j);`

Answer (score 0):

The size of the array cannot be changed dynamically in Java, as it is done in C/C++. Hence in order to add an element in the array, one of the following methods can be done:

- Create a new array of size n+1, where n is the size of the original array.
- Add the n elements of the original array in this array.
- Add the new element in the n+1 th position.
- Print the new array.

There is no `add(object)` method in an array.

In this case, you should be assigning a variable to an index in the array like so:

```
tmp[i] = inventory.get(j);
```

So your code should look like:

```
public MediaItem [] findItems(String callNumber)
{
    MediaItem[] tmp = new MediaItem[MAX_ITEMS];
    for (int i = 0; i <= inventory.size(); i++)
    {
        int j = inventory.indexOf(callNumber);
        
        tmp[i] = inventory.get(j);
        return tmp;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That will at least compile now, though my tests are giving me null pointer exceptions for everything

Comment: @BailySchmeltzer Glad to help! If this answers your question, pleas consider upvoting!

Comment: are you able to explain why it isn't actually adding the items to the array? It is just giving me null pointer exceptions every time

Comment: @BailySchmeltzer You never defined the Object `inventory`.

Comment: Inventory is defined as an ArrayList earlier in the code.

Comment: @BailySchmeltzer Then it should be `inventory.get(key)`.